# Unable to use do-while loop correctly to implement a bubble sort

Tags: c, bubble-sort

```
//create swap function 
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
//implement swap function
int temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = temp;
}

void sort(int arrayofval[], int n)
{
int burst = 0;
do
{
  for(int i=0, burst = 0; i < n; i++)
  if(arrayofval[i] > arrayofval[i+1])
  {
  swap(&arrayofval[i], &arrayofval[i+1]);
  burst++; 
  }
}
while(burst != 0);
return;
```

Hiya! I'm trying to implement a bubble sort and swap function in C and an hitting a bit of a wall :-( When debugging, it seems that my swap function and initial loop work. However, it seems that my function exits after the first looping and doesn't repeat the loop > swap values process because the condition for:

while(burst != 0)

isn't running. Could anyone help me understand this a bit more?

Comment: Is your array already sorted?

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't notice anything particularly suspicious, but I suspect that if you step through this code using a debugger you'll see very quickly why it's not working. Best of luck.

Comment: My array isn't sorted unfortunately, I used 4,3,2 as inputs in order and had 3,2,4 returned after one loop. I expected the loop to run again due to the while(burst != 0) condition, however the function simply returned after the first run. 

I didn't see the while(burst... run in the debugger, so that was curious to me.

Comment: Code has 2 `burst` declarations.  The outside `burst`, used in `while(burst != 0);`  is not updated by `burst++;`.  That is the inside `burst`.

Comment: @chux Thank you! If I changed the `burst` within the loop to `&burst`, would that allow me to edit the exterior `burst` directly?

Comment: No.  Code still has 2 `burst`: `int burst = 0;` ... `for(int i=0, burst = 0;` and `for(int i=0, &burst = 0;` make doth not compile.

Answer (score 2):

It works just fine, except that you should do `i < n-1`, because `arrayofval[i+1]` would point beyond the array for `i = n-1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void sort(int arrayofval[], int n)
{
    int burst, i = 0;
    do
    {
        for(i=0, burst = 0; i < n-1; i++)
            if(arrayofval[i] > arrayofval[i+1])
            {
                swap(&arrayofval[i], &arrayofval[i+1]);
                burst++; 
            }
    }
    while(burst != 0);
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    int list[] = {3,2,1};
    sort( list, 3 );
    printf("%d %d %d\n", list[0], list[1], list[2] );
}
```

Comment: Noticed code also dropped the declaration of `burst` from the `for` loop - a necessary step.

Comment: Indeed, and that of `i`. It's C after all!

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing out both! I thought that I could declare burst outside of the for loop -- is this notion incorrect?

Comment: In your original code it didn't make a difference: you reset burst in the INIT block of the for loop. But in classic C, you can only declare variables at the beginning of a code block (`{}`). The `for (int` gave a compilation error: `error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode`.

Comment: Confident classic C allows for declaration at the beginning of each block `{`, not just  at the beginning of the method.  Minor issue anyways.